# Should I always set worker_processes to the number of CPU in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up a VPS with 4 vCPU that will be running a single website.

Most places recommend to set the nginx `worker_processes` config to the number of cpus, so in this case 4.

The server will also be running a few other services (mysql, memcached mainly) that will be used by the website.

In that current scenario, is it still recommended to have `worker_processes` set to 4 or would there be benefits to limiting it to 3 for instance?

**Edit:** Also running php, via php-fpm - don't know how I didn't think that was relevant

Answer (score 1):

In this case, even 1 should be fine, as MySQL and Memcache will likely use much more CPU than nginx. As I imagine, you will also run some kind of scripting language on it as well, which would be even more intensive.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it's also running php-fpm and you're also correct that these would be more intensive. Would the 4 worker_processes negatively affect other processes though?

Comment: If they do get to actually use the CPU, yes. IMHO you should try to keep a balance between these. On the other hand, you will reach a bottleneck much faster on PHP and MySQL so nginx will not get to use the CPU I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It for sure depends on the load you are expecting on your VPS.

Normally I would just go with the recommendation and let the underlying OS do its job to get the most out of your VPS, though Nginx is quite ressource lightweight and might do fine as well on one core only.

Comment: Same question as Florin.. Would the 4 worker_processes negatively affect other processes?

Comment: As I told, it depends on what you are exactly doing on your VPS. the safe bet is normally to go with the recommendation so that the OS can possibly divide the load equally on all cores, Nginx is normally quite nice to the CPU.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the recommendation"? 4?

Comment: Yes, of course 4, like you stated in your own question.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance there is no harm in setting the worker processes to the same as your CPU cores.

Most of the processor operations that NGINX performs are basic enough that they will be handled in L1 cache of your CPU, and will not impact other services on your server.

As always, it depends on the server load and your configuration, however, I run a website that  receives around 6,000,000+ hits per day and the CPU does not even reach 10%. It's also running MySQL and PHP-FPM, and APM for caching.

Comment: Ok, very good to know..